Recalculate Normals outside works as flip Normals
I have the issue in multiple objects that some normal faces are red. I'd like to recalculate all normal of multiple objects to blue but it does not work. I tried with one object but the option Recalculate Outside works as flip normals.
I want all the faces to be blue.

When Blender has problems to orient all faces in a uniform way then this is usually an indicator that there is something wrong with your mesh and it is non-manifold - i.e. a geometry like that could not exist in reality, simply spoken. When Recalculate Normals or Shift+N cannot make them all uniform due to non-manifold edges/faces, the Inside option there or the Recalculate Outside tool cannot change this fact.
So basically yes, Recalculate Outside and Recalculate Inside sometimes work like Alt+N > Flip Normals but with the difference that Flip Normals always flips the normals no matter how they are oriented, while Recalculate Normals/Outside/Inside orients them all uniformly (or at least tries to as much as possible). And if they are already oriented in the direction you choose (and are recognized as that), the option will not flip anything.
What you can do about it is either only select those faces which seem to be oriented incorrectly and then either recalculate them with Outside/Inside whatever is needed or Flip Normals - but if this is due to non-manifold geometry, whenever you use the Recalculate... tool again, the incorrect faces might be reversed again.
Unless you know there are flaws in your mesh but you accept them because they do not matter or cannot be avoided for some reason, I would recommend to find why the faces are oriented incorrectly and try to repair them in one way or another.

Thank you so much for the information.
